# Is it possible to align LaTeX lines of code to the left instead of the right?

Tags: macos, latex

I've just started using LaTeX that is included in MacOS' Pages. It's been really helpful for writing physics formulas and such, but I tried to write a solution with multiple lines for a lab report, and everything is aligning to the right. I can't find anything online to move it leftwards; a lot of commands don't work with it.

Here's what I have:

```
cosΘ = {B_{horizontal}\over B_{total}} \\
cosΘ = {98\over 132} \\
cosΘ = 0.7424242424 \\
Θ = cos^{-1}0.7424242424 \\
Θ = 42.1\,\,degrees
\end{align}
```

But it's showing up
 [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTawr.png)
Is there a way to get it aligned like the picture, but to the left instead of the right? I've tried for at least an hour to find a solution that works to display what I want.

Thank you in advance! Please know I'm new to this and have only been using this for about two months. I'm sorry if I'm missing anything obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` to set the points where the equations are vertically aligned. And instead of `cos` use the command `\cos`. I also use `\text`.

```latex
\begin{align}
   \cos \theta &= \frac{B_{\text{horizontal}}}{B_{\text{total}}} \\
   \cos \theta &= \frac{98}{132} \\
   \cos \theta &= 0.7424242424 \\
   \theta      &= \cos^{-1}0.7424242424 \\
   \theta      &= 42.1 \text{ degrees}.
\end{align}
```

I misread your question and assume that you would prefer to align the `=`. To align the lines to the left, you can use the `&` at the beginning of the lines.

```latex
\begin{align}
   &\cos \theta = \frac{B_{\text{horizontal}}}{B_{\text{total}}} \\
   &\cos \theta = \frac{98}{132} \\
   &\cos \theta = 0.7424242424 \\
   &\theta      = \cos^{-1}0.7424242424 \\
   &\theta      = 42.1 \text{ degrees}.
\end{align}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot! :D

One more question: do you know how I would add a degrees sign º into the final answer, instead of typing out the word? It won't let me use the alt/option shortcut. I tried \degree too but to no avail.

Comment: There's a lot of way. You can use the command `\degree` of the package `gensymb`. A more complete package to deal with units is `siunitx`which also have a `\degree` command. And you can obtain the symbol easily with `^{\circ}`, but it's a bit rough and you will not have the correct spacing. So, `\degree` of `siunitx` is probably the best solution (especially if you want to manage other units).